# Whats the difference in the meaning between the given sentences?

Tags: meaning

> Would you mind **waiting** for an hour?

and

> Would you mind **to wait** for an hour?

Comment: The second is non-standard (for British, and I would guess, US English). It may be standard in South Asian dialects of English.

Comment: Is there no difference in their meanings?

Comment: The latter would be very unusual in AmE.

Comment: @Kaushik As the second one is non-standard ("ungrammatical") in dialects I am familiar with, I cannot comment on what it might mean in any dialect where it is acceptable (if there are any).

Answer (score 3):

The first one using a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) which is a noun;
The second sentence has a verb;

In this situation, it is better to use a gerund. The gerund is perfect to use in the role of:

- **Subject**  *Eating cake is pleasant.*
- **Extraposed subject**   *It can be pleasant eating cakes.*
- **Subject Complement**   *What    I'm looking forward to is eating cakes*
- **Direct object**    *I    can't stop eating cakes.*
- **Prepositional object**     *I dreamt of    eating cakes.*
- **Adverbial**    *He walks the streets eating cakes.*
- **Part of noun phrase**  *It's a picture of a man eating cakes.*
- **Part of adjective phrase**     *They are all busy eating cakes.*
- **Complement of preposition**    *She takes pleasure in eating cakes.*

[What are gerunds and how do you use them](https://www.eurocentres.com/blog/what-are-gerunds-and-how-do-you-use-them/)